# C# - StackTrace | calls method when "FrameCount" changed

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, .net-core

I need to know when a function is called and a function is ended. 
Otherwise i need to detect everytime when the "**StackTrace.FrameCount**" is changed.

My idea was to insert my function into the Setter of the "StackTrace.FrameCount" and Redirect to the base-function of FrameCount but ...
the problem is, "StackTrace.FrameCount" has only an GETTER.

```
    //
    // Zusammenfassung:
    //     Gets the number of frames in the stack trace.
    //
    // Rückgabewerte:
    //     The number of frames in the stack trace.
    public virtual int FrameCount { get; }
```

Is there any possibility to make an PropertyChangedEventHandler or something else to manage this Problem?

Many Thanks! :)

Thomas

Comment: Can you give us some context of _why_ you are doing this? _In case there is an alternative solution._ Which version of .NET Core are you using?

Comment: I need to make a "Performance-Watch", how much time is spent for each function. Now its very hard because i need to insert a method call in the beginning of a function and at the end. I use .Net-Core 2.1.

Comment: There is no way to do this as simple as you want it to be, as the code runs nothing is maintained that contains the current stack trace, instead a stack trace is produced on demand. Please explain which problem you're trying to solve where this is a solution, there has to be a different and better way to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Typically performance profilers either take a snapshot of where each thread is currently at N times a second and constructs the call stacks from this, or they instrument the code by adding code to each method entry and exit. I have no idea how to do the former, the latter could be done by mono.cecil or ildasm/ilasm or similar. Either way it's going to be a good portion of work. Are you sure there are no existing tools you can use instead for this, such as [dotTrace](https://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/?fromMenu) ?

Comment: Also, do you really ned method-level performance measurements? Can't you use BenchmarkDotNet to benchmark your code instead?

Comment: I've some project specific measurements in my own performance watch and so i don't want to use another performance tracker :/ Sadly that there is no way to detect when a method is called or finished... but many Thanks Karlsen :)

Comment: I assume you're looking for some AOP method to intercept method calls, check out MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody (https://github.com/vescon/MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody), we used that to implement a performance check by decorating methods with a custom attribute.

Comment: Exactly what i´m looking for :D Thank you @Lennart !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for some kind of AOP to intercept method entry and exit "events". An easy way is for example [MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody](https://github.com/vescon/MethodBoundaryAspect.Fody), which enables you to write a custom attribute that exposes three different methods for interception, `OnEntry`, `OnExit` and `OnException`. To measure performance of a method you can simple start a stopwatch in `OnEntry` and stop and display the elapsed time in `OnExit`.